# Firestore Multiprovider doesn't work for authentication

Tags: flutter, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJ5Vrya3wCQ, but I get an error of Provider (I think) when I try to run it.

I am getting almost the same main page except for the homePage() and signInPage() that are my own pages.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fyzik_flutter/views/authenticate/authentication_service.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:fyzik_flutter/views/authenticate/signup.dart';
import 'package:fyzik_flutter/views/tabs.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';



Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  //setup();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) => context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
          initialData: null,
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      return MaterialApp(home: TabsPage());
    }
    return MaterialApp(home: SignupPage());
  }
}
```

The error seems to be coming from the line where I try to get a `User` from `context.watch<User>();`

I get this error :

````
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building AuthenticationWrapper(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<User> above this AuthenticationWrapper Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that AuthenticationWrapper is under your MultiProvider/Provider<User>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
````

I already tried to change the code accordingly to what the text recommend here but I still get the same error.

At the moment, I think the Multiprovider isn't getting any context to work on in the method watch but I'm not sure of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get a `Provider` of type `User` in this line:

`final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();`

but your `StreamProvider` does not have a type specified.

**Solution:**

You need to specify the type for the `StreamProvider` like this:

```dart
StreamProvider<User>(
  create: (context) => context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
  initialData: null,
)
```

Comment: That worked ! I just also had to set initialData to an empty User and everything was solved :-)